# How to setup an environment for testing a SAS database?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sas

I need to test calling a SAS database from a .NET application, preferably using NHibernate as ORM. How do I setup up a trial version of SAS for testing on my machine, is it even possible? Seems to me there are very many components to install and I can't find any trial version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get a trial version of SAS is to contact SAS directly.  It's not available to be downloaded or installed without a license.  SAS does offer 30-day trial copy (and because of software "dies" 90 days after expiration, you really have four months to test).

If you choose to get a trial copy, be sure to discuss your target application requirements.  Opening SAS data from .NET requires a component called the IOM server, which is part of either the `SAS Enterprise BI Server` or the `SAS Integration Technologies` software.  However, if your application only needs to **READ** SAS data sets, you might consider other solutions.  If you want to go that route, ask a new question.

[Here is a link](http://support.sas.com/kb/=?ct=58043&s1=3&qt=&la=en&qm=3&rf=4) with several SAS notes on .NET programming with SAS.

Comment: Thanks! Thought I wouldn't get any answers :) I only need to read data from SAS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531668/how-to-read-datasets-from-sas-using-nhibernate