# How to read datasets from SAS using NHibernate?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sas

I need to read datasets from SAS into a .NET application, preferably through NHibernate. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know anything about NHibernate, but accessing SAS datasets through .NET is typically accomplished through a OLEDB connection or ADO (or ADO.NET).  SAS docs contain the necessary information, see for example  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/oledbpr/63701/HTML/default/viewer.htm#titlepage.htm

All of these require an installation of SAS on the machine you're reading them from (or a machine you can connect to).

Alan Churchhill (http://savian.net/) has also written a .NET reader that does not require a SAS installation, but it is not free.

Comment: please update the link above (http://savian.net/) by the way, very helpful answer.